# Can ruby deep search a hash/array for a particular key?

Tags: ruby, arrays, json, api, hash

I have some ruby code that gets a json from Jenkins that contains an array of n items. The item I want has a key called "lastBuiltRevision"

I know I can loop through the array like so

```
actions.each do |action| 
    if action["lastBuiltRevision"]
        lastSuccessfulRev = action["lastBuiltRevision"]["SHA1"]
        break
    end
end
```

but that feels very clunky and devoid of the magic that I usually feel when working with ruby.

I have only been tinkering with it for roughly a week now, and I feel that I may be missing something to make this easier/faster.

Is there such a thing? or is manual iteration all I can do?

I am kind of hoping for something like

```
lastSuccessfulRev = action.match("lastBuildRevision/SHA1")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`Enumerable#find`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-find):

```
actions = [
  {'dummy' => true },
  {'dummy' => true },
  {'dummy' => true },
  {'lastBuiltRevision' => { "SHA1" => "123abc" }},
  {'dummy' => true },
]
actions.find { |h|
  h.has_key? 'lastBuiltRevision'
}['lastBuiltRevision']['SHA1']
# => "123abc"
```

**UPDATE**

Above code will throw `NoMethodError` if there's no matched item. Use follow code if you don't want get an exception.

```
rev = actions.find { |h| h.has_key? 'lastBuiltRevision' }
rev = rev['lastBuiltRevision']['SHA1'] if rev
```

Comment: ...and if one doesn't exist?

Comment: it would return nil right? I am already nil checking this value in my code for other purposes.

Comment: @Kronusdark, It will throw exception `NoMethodError` because `Enumerable#find` return `nil` if there's no matched item.

Comment: `h.has_key?('lastBuiltRevision')` should be enough, why `fetch`?

Comment: @VictorMoroz, You're right. I updated the answer according to you. Thank you for comment.

Comment: ft, why would you choose to raise an exception when the first key is not present but return `nil` if only the second key is not present?  You might consider `h = actions.find { |h| h.has_key? 'lastBuiltRevision'}; h ? h['lastBuiltRevision']['SHA1'] : nil`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to do it, making use of the form of [Enumerable#find](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) that takes a parameter `ifnone` which is called, and its return value returned, if `find`'s block never evaluates `true`.

I assume the method is to return `nil` if either key is not found.

**Code**

```
def look_for(actions, k1, k2)
  actions.find(->{{k1=>{}}}) { |e| e.key?(k1) }[k1][k2]
end
```

**Examples**

```
actions = [{ 'dog'=>'woof' }, { 'lastBuiltRevision'=>{ 'SHA1'=> 2 } }]

look_for(actions, 'lastBuiltRevision', 'SHA1') #=> 2
look_for(actions, 'cat, 'SHA1')                #=> nil
look_for(actions, 'lastBuiltRevision', 'cat')  #=> nil
```

**Explanation**

I've made `find`'s `ifnone` parameter the lambda:

```
l = ->{{k1=>{}}}
```

so that:

```
k1 = "cats"
h  = l.call   #=> {"cats"=>{}}
h[k1]['SHA1'] #=> {}['SHA1']
              #=> nil
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
action.map { |a| a["lastBuiltRevision"] }.compact.map { |lb| lb["SHA1"] }.first
```

Comment: A little wordier than I would like, but it works and is less loopy (at least in appearances)

Comment: @Kronusdark Only it scans and processes all actions while you need one, `find` is a better way.